# Source not found for hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar when debugging hadoop 2.2.0 in eclipse

Tags: debugging, hadoop, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug my mapreduce programs in eclispe. I put `export HADOOP_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5002"` in `hadoop-env.sh` and configured eclipse for remote debugging on port 5002 of localhost.

It starts debugging fine in `main` but when it comes to `job.waitForCompletion(true);` it fails with a new file `JobSubmitter.class` which says:

```
Source not found
The JAR file /home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jarhas no source attachment. You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below.
```

How could I debug map and reduce functions or even my `RecoredRedader` class?

Comment: Sam, could you maybe put more detail in your question as to how you went about debugging mapreduce in eclipse.

Comment: @erichfw did you try [Hadoop eclipse plugin](https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sources are packed into a different JAR. In your case you must look for the path `share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources`.

In there exists the `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0-sources.jar` that you must provide in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This was the easiest problem i met in hadoop. :)
You just got to click on Attach Sources and select the required *-sources.jar in the sources folder.

If you got an error for hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar then you got to attach hadoop-common-2.2.0-source.jar